# Verify that $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{{\rm d}\theta}{(1-m^2\cos^2{\theta})^2}= \frac{(2-m^2)\pi}{4(1-m^2)^{3/2}}$ for $0<m<1$

Tags: integration

I am told that the integral

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(1-m^2\cos^2{\theta})^2}\,{\rm d}\theta\\
&= \frac{(2-m^2)\pi}{4(1-m^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}

Where $0<m<1$. I want to verify this however I have no idea on how this is done. Can someone explain?

I was thinking possibly a substitution so I tried $x=m\cos\theta$ however this makes the problem more complicated so obviously it's wrong.

Comment: for what is $\epsilon$ for?

Comment: Sorry - you can ignore that (it is just part of the calculation this is embedded in). I have removed it now.

Comment: weierstrass sub will solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing Weierstrass substitution $\theta=2\arctan\frac{t}{2}$,  it is probably faster to directly perform the substitution $\theta=\arctan t$, leading to $d\theta=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$ and $\frac{1}{1+t^2}=\cos^2\theta$, so that

$$ I(m) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1+t^2}{(1-m^2+t^2)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-m^2)^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1+(1-m^2)u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}\,du $$
and the integrals
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^2}=\frac{\pi}{4},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2\,du}{(1+u^2)^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
can be computed in various ways, for instance through the residue theorem. They lead to:
$$ I(m)=\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{2-m^2}{(1-m^2)^{3/2}} $$
as wanted. Another efficient trick is to recognize in the integral some multiple of the area enclosed by an ellipse, due to the polar equation of an ellipse and the formula for computing the area in polar coordinates.

**Update:** I would really like the downvoters explaining their downvotes. What is wrong here?

Comment: It is "faster" than what?

Comment: @Dr.MV: Than performing Weierstrass substitution $\theta=2\arctan\frac{t}{2}$.

Comment: It's not really faster than first using Feynman's Trick to simplify the task considerably.  ;-))

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}\,du = 0$$ also follows from enforcing the substitution $u\mapsto \frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: well, if someone here computes $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^2}$ without using the residue theorem, there is no derivative to compute!

Comment: Perhaps we need to test the "faster" hypothesis.  LOL

Comment: Is any of this really all that relevant?  Where is the OP asking for the fastest possible method to work the problem out by hand?

Comment: @RonGordon  It's not.  I was simply questioning "faster" statement.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

The integral of interest $I(m)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(1-m^2\cos^2(\theta))^2}\,d\theta$ can be readily simplified as

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(1-m^2\cos^2(\theta))^2}\,d\theta\\\\
&=-\frac2{m^4}\left.\frac{d}{da}\left(\int_{0}^\pi\frac{1}{a-\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\right)\right|_{a=2/m^2 -1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, either simply enforce the classical [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), use contour integration, or just recall the well-known result to arrive at

$$\begin{align}
I&=-\frac2{m^4}\left.\frac{d}{da}\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)\right|_{a=2/m^2 -1}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi(2-m^2)}{4(1-m^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 0):

Let $t = \tan \theta = \frac {\sin \theta} {\cos \theta}$. Combining this with the identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$ and keeping in mind that $\theta \in [0, \frac \pi 2]$ (where $\cos \theta \ge 0$), we obtain $\cos^2 \theta = \frac 1 {1+t^2}$. With this substitution the integral becomes

$$\int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac 1 {(1 - m^2 \frac 1 {1 + t^2})^2} \frac 1 {1+t^2} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac {t^2 + 1} {(t^2 + 1 - m^2)^2} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac 1 {t^2 + 1 - m^2} \ \Bbb d t + \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac {m^2} {(t^2 + 1 - m^2)^2} \ \Bbb d t .$$

The first one, by the change of variable $t = \sqrt {1-m^2} u$, becomes

$$\frac 1 {\sqrt {1-m^2}} \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac 1 {1+u^2} \ \Bbb d u = \frac 1 {\sqrt {1-m^2}} \arctan u \big| _0 ^\infty = \frac \pi 2 \frac 1 {\sqrt {1-m^2}} .$$

With the same change of variable, the second one becomes

$$\frac {m^2} {\sqrt {1-m^2} ^3} \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac 1 {(1+u^2)^2} \ \Bbb d u .$$

For this last integral, perform the change of variables $u = \tan s$, obtaining

$$\frac {m^2} {\sqrt {1-m^2} ^3} \int \limits _0 ^\frac \pi 2 \frac 1 {(1 + \tan^2 s)^2} \frac 1 {\cos^2 s} \Bbb d s = \frac {m^2} {\sqrt {1-m^2} ^3} \int \limits _0 ^\frac \pi 2 \frac 1 {\frac 1 {\cos^4 s}} \frac 1 {\cos^2 s} \Bbb d s = \frac {m^2} {\sqrt {1-m^2} ^3} \int \limits _0 ^\frac \pi 2 \cos^2 s \ \Bbb d s = \\
\frac {m^2} {\sqrt {1-m^2} ^3} \int \limits _0 ^\frac \pi 2 \frac {1 + \cos 2s} 2 \ \Bbb d s = \frac \pi 4 \frac {m^2} {\sqrt {1-m^2} ^3} .$$

Adding the two integrals, we get

$$\frac \pi 4 \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 - m^2}} \left( 2 + \frac {m^2} {1-m^2} \right) = \frac \pi 4 \frac {2-m^2} {(1-m^2) ^\frac 3 2} .$$

Comment: This is the same as @JackD'Aurizio's answer, but when I noticed his post mine was almost finished, therefore I don't feel like deleting it after all this typing.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\ }
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbx{\left.
\vphantom{\Huge A^{a}}%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over \bracks{1 - m^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}^{2}}
\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ m\ <\ 1}} =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over \bracks{1 - m^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{t\ \equiv\ \tan\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{2} + 1 \over \pars{t^{2} + 1 - m^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd t =
m^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{t^{2} + 1 - m^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1 - m^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{{1 \over 2}\,m\,\totald{}{m} + 1}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1 - m^{2}}}
_{\color{#f00}{\ds{{\pi \over 2}\,{1 \over \root{1 - m^{2}}}}}}\ =\
{\pi \over 2}\pars{{1 \over 2}\,m\,\totald{}{m} + 1}
{1 \over \root{1 - m^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{\pi \over 4}\,{2 - m^{2} \over \pars{1 - m^{2}}^{3/2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $m\cos\left(\theta\right)<1
 $ we get $$I\left(m\right)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\left(1-m^{2}\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)\right)^{2}}d\theta
 $$ $$=\sum_{k\geq1}km^{2k-2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2k-2}\left(\theta\right)d\theta
 $$ $$=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{km^{2k-2}\Gamma\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\left(k-1\right)!}\tag{1}
 $$ where $(1)$ follows from the definition of Beta function in the following form $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2a-1}\left(\theta\right)\cos^{2b-1}\left(\theta\right)d\theta=\frac{B\left(a.b\right)}{2},a,b>0,$$ so $$I\left(m\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(k+1\right)m^{2k}\left(2k\right)!}{k!^{2}4^{k}}\tag{2}
 $$ where $(2)
 $ follows from [this identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General), hence $$I\left(m\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k\geq1}\dbinom{2k}{k}\left(k+1\right)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^{2k}
 $$ but from the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) we know that $$\sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{2k}{k}x^{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^{2}}}
 $$ hence $$I\left(m\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{2-m^{2}}{\left(1-m^{2}\right)^{3/2}}}$$ as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(1-\alpha^2\cos^2\theta)^2} d\theta
= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(1-\alpha^2\cos^2\theta)^2} d\theta.$$

where $0\lt\alpha\lt 1.$

Introduce $z=\exp(i\theta)$ so that $dz=iz \; d\theta$ to get
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{(1-\alpha^2(z+1/z)^2/4)^2} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = \frac{1}{4}\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{z^4}{(z^2-\alpha^2(z^2+1)^2/4)^2} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = \frac{1}{4i}\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{z^3}{(z^2-\alpha^2(z^2+1)^2/4)^2} \; dz.$$

With  the substitution  $z^2 =  w$  and supposing  $\Gamma$ being  the
contour where we loop around the origin twice this is

$$\frac{1}{4i}\int_{\Gamma}
\frac{w}{(w-\alpha^2(w+1)^2/4)^2} \; \frac{1}{2} dw
\\ = \frac{1}{4i}\int_{|w|=1}
\frac{w}{(w-\alpha^2(w+1)^2/4)^2} \; dw.$$

The poles are at

$$\rho_{0,1} = \frac{2-\alpha^2\pm 2\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\alpha^2}
= -1 + \frac{2}{\alpha^2} 
\pm \frac{2}{\alpha^2} \sqrt{1-\alpha^2}.$$

Now with $\alpha\lt 1$ we get $2/\alpha^2 > 2$ or $-1+2/\alpha^2\gt 1$
and  with   $2\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}/\alpha^2$  positive   $\rho_0$  cannot
possibly be inside the contour. Observe however that

$$\rho_0\rho_1 =
\frac{1}{\alpha^4} ((2-\alpha^2)^2-4(1-\alpha^2)) = 1$$

and  therefore $\rho_1  = 1/\rho_0$  is inside  the contour.  Call the
integrand $f(w).$ The desired quantity is then given by

$$2\pi i \times \frac{1}{4i} \mathrm{Res}_{w=\rho_1} f(w).$$

To find the residue we write

$$f(w) = \frac{w}{(w-\alpha^2(w+1)^2/4)^2} 
= \frac{1}{(-\alpha^2/4)^2} \frac{w}{(w-\rho_0)^2 (w-\rho_1)^2}
\\ = \frac{16}{\alpha^4} \frac{1}{(w-\rho_0)^2 (w-\rho_1)}
+ \rho_1 \frac{16}{\alpha^4} \frac{1}{(w-\rho_0)^2 (w-\rho_1)^2}.$$

The contribution from the first term is

$$\frac{16}{\alpha^4} \frac{1}{((-4/\alpha^2) \sqrt{1-\alpha^2})^2}
= \frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}.$$

For the second term we have that

$$\frac{1}{(w-\rho_0)^2} = \frac{1}{(\rho_1-\rho_0)^2}
- \frac{2}{(\rho_1-\rho_0)^3} (w-\rho_1) + \cdots$$

Therefore the contribution is

$$-\rho_1\frac{16}{\alpha^4}
\frac{2}{((-4/\alpha^2)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2})^3}
= \rho_1\frac{\alpha^2}{4}
\frac{2}{(1-\alpha^2)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}
\\ = \left(-1+\frac{2}{\alpha^2}\right)\frac{\alpha^2}{4}
\frac{2}{(1-\alpha^2)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}
- \frac{2}{\alpha^2} \sqrt{1-\alpha^2} \frac{\alpha^2}{4}
\frac{2}{(1-\alpha^2)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}
\\ = \left(-1+\frac{2}{\alpha^2}\right)\frac{\alpha^2}{4}
\frac{2}{(1-\alpha^2)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}
-\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}.$$

Adding the two contributions the  term $1/(1-\alpha^2)$ cancels and we
are left with

$$2\pi i \times \frac{1}{4i}
\times \frac{1}{2} (2-\alpha^2)  
\frac{1}{(1-\alpha^2)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}$$

for an end result of

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\pi}{4} (2-\alpha^2) \frac{1}{(1-\alpha^2)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}.}$$